# change of resistance in semiconductors due to temperature change

Tags: homework-and-exercises, temperature, semiconductor-physics

I have a question that popped up in an old exam I just can't find a way to solve.

> If you drop the temperature of this material from room temperature (I guess around 300K) to 0C (273K) the resistance drops with a factor of 3.5.

Is it: silicon, germanium or gallium arsenide ?

I've been googling, looking through the books for the last 2h and just can't find any way to solve this question.

Any idea?

Comment: i could only find the formula:

Comment: p = p_o * e^(a*T)  but this gives factors of sizes up to 10^295 which is rediculous :/

Comment: Notice anything about the SIGN of the coefficient for semiconductors?

Comment: By the way, I guess you meant silicon, not silicone.

Comment: oh yes clearly silicon (sry im swiss, in german its called 'silicium' confusing..) and yes it should be -aT but still i dont get to 3.5 onany, maybe iused the wrong a..

Comment: It seems even [Britney Spears](http://britneyspears.ac/lasers.htm) does not know the answer to this question. I think you have to find a good reference with material properties for Si, Ge and GaAs, otherwise one can only guess what the coefficient `a` is for the different materials.

Comment: i finally found the answer =) for anyone who is ineterested:

$\rho(T)=\rho_0\cdot e^{-\frac{E_g}{2k_BT}}$

so the factor would be

$\frac{\rho(Room)}{\rho(273.15)}=e^{-\frac{E_g}{2k_B300K}+\frac{E_g}{2k_B273.15K}}$

to achieve 3,5 as factore we change the equation to find $E_g$ and get

$E_g=-ln(3.5)\cdot 2k_B\cdot \frac{1}{\frac{1}{300K}-\frac{1}{273.15K}}\approx 0.65$ which is very close to 0.67, the bandgap of germanium. 

thanks for helping anyways =)

Comment: haha thank you for this funny link :P as said - i was able to solve it myself =)

Comment: @Sebastian Flückiger: what is $\rho$ in your formula, or maybe you could give a reference?

Comment: @Sebastian Flückiger: It would be great if you can post your answer as a answer(as opposed to a comment), so the question doesn't become an orphan.

Comment: i couldnt because i had too little reputation. i will as soon as i get to a conputer (just cell here). rho is the specific resistance @akhmeteli

Comment: @Sebastian Flückiger: Then your formula may be incorrect. For example, the same formula is written for conductivity at http://www.virginia.edu/bohr/mse209/chapter19.htm (para 19.12)

Comment: wheras conductivity and resistance indirectly proportional so it does not really matter which one you calculate =) if the resistance drops with a factor 3.5 the conductivity goes up by the same factor, and vice versa.

Comment: @Sebastian Flückiger: I agree. However, in your question, resistivity rises with temperature, whereas in the correct formula, resistivity falls with temperature. Therefore, it seems that your answer is incorrect, and the formula is inapplicable. You should look at specific properties of the semiconductors in question, rather than use a generic formula.

Answer (score 1):

i finally found the answer =) for anyone who is ineterested:

$\rho(T)=\rho_0\cdot e^{-\frac{E_g}{2k_BT}}$

so the factor would be

$\frac{\rho(Room)}{\rho(273.15)}=e^{-\frac{E_g}{2k_B300K}+\frac{E_g}{2k_B273.15K}}$

to achieve 3,5 as factore we change the equation to find $E_g$ and get

$E_g=-ln(3.5)\cdot 2k_B\cdot \frac{1}{\frac{1}{300K}-\frac{1}{273.15K}}\approx 0.65 eV$

which is very close to 0.67eV the bandgap of Germanium - hence germanium is the solution.